# Are finitely generated projective models of an algebraic theory always finitely presented?

Tags: category-theory, modules, universal-algebra, projective-module, finitely-generated

I know that for modules over rings, a finitely generated projective module is finitely presented. I was wondering whether this holds in full generality for algebraic theories, and if not, which parts of the abelian structure of the category of modules are needed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $P$ is a finitely generated projective $\mathbb{T}$-algebra. Then there is a finitely generated free $\mathbb{T}$-algebra $F$ and a surjective homomorphism $r : F \to P$, and since $P$ is projective, there is also a homomorphism $s : P \to F$ such that $r \circ s = \mathrm{id}_P$. Then, $r : F \to P$ is the coequaliser of $\mathrm{id}_F$ and $s \circ r$, so $P$ is also a finitely presented $\mathbb{T}$-algebra.

More generally, if you have an $\mathcal{E}$-projective object $P$ in a locally finitely presentable category and an $\mathcal{E}$-morphism $F \to P$ where $F$ is a finitely presentable object, then $P$ is also a finitely presentable object.

Comment: How can I see any other map $f$ with $fsr=f$ factors through $r$?

Comment: If $f \circ s \circ r = f$ then $(f \circ s) \circ r = f$...

Comment: Oh god, sorry :)